# Return discriminated union from factory function in typescript

Tags: typescript, factory, typescript-generics, return-type, discriminated-union

I'm trying to return an object from a factory function and give it an exact type based on a discriminated union. I've summarised into a much simplified code sample below, but whilst hovering over the newSquare object shows that the complier knows that it is a Square, I'm getting an error on return new Circle of:

> Type 'Circle' is not assignable to type 'DiscriminateUnion<Circle, "kind", T> | DiscriminateUnion<Square, "kind", T>'.
> Type 'Circle' is not assignable to type 'DiscriminateUnion<Square, "kind", T>'.(2322)

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks!

```
type ShapeKind = 'circle' | 'square'

class Circle{

  kind: "circle" = 'circle';
  radius: number;
    constructor() {
        this.radius = 4
    }
}

class Square{
  kind: "square" = 'square';
  sideLength: number;

      constructor() {
        this.sideLength = 4
    }

}

type Shape = Circle | Square;

type DiscriminateUnion<T, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]> =
  T extends Record<K, V> ? T : never

function makeShape<T extends ShapeKind>(shapeKind: T): DiscriminateUnion<Shape, 'kind', T> {
    switch (shapeKind) {
        case 'circle':
            return new Circle()

        case 'square':
            return new Square()

        default:
        throw Error('not valid shape')

    }
}

const newSquare = makeShape('square')
```

[Link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=45&ssc=38&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAygFgQ0gaQJYDsAmUC8UDkAxqgE6EA2E+UAPgQM4COArgiVQLABQ3A9L1AzAIJAGYJC0eEmgBvPgKhKoAawyYAXLEQp1CqAF9u3Cgnr0oAYVIUI8nlyVqsWgETEylV7gIfb+AG5uJRIETFRmei10ZgBbACMRIMdlQgB7dHpgEmZCYDSSAAoASih7ZQqoYDhUegA6UPDInwAWYOUjLk6TcjMLGBY2O3bnTShXJlZ2bzx8SaHA9vpUTAgAGQh0AHNq6LjEkmT2ivTM7Nz8otLyyqVq2rrl1Y3t6tbjw2Mur9BIbRkfNZPNA6AMphAjlxftAACK1QgkVCxDAIYQAVXQqAyAB4ACoAGigyCgEAAHsIsBYVBAQGlRFACVAAGok8mbTAWXEAbWQAF0AHy4dq41kUjlQABKEHSJEw2OQhKZgoA-AyoNEIAA3ERfUTMdB5LHoKCxBDU6SQPGi9n9HQQNBYfmFeh2h1jXHFLRw+gIpEo9GYnEWiCE-CjfCE3GCm5KegAd1QwEIcCgztd6muHxOZmgRBslHwGiztyg7GAzBIxvQEDjVnzEBKXxLUEIOYYg3YheLtzLFarNdgHYbxSbJdW4mY5GARZSt2qJDStYAoiQF0V8Og0sAoJqEOQVlAXTJ8COHBVOt0uKcslBq3GwUMfKbzXbCnMhyegA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a well known problem. The compiler has no way to verify that concrete returned type is compatible with the conditional type depending on generic type parameter. You may read about the exact limitations here [microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912).

Beside the obvious type assertion of the returned result:

```ts
function makeShape<T extends ShapeKind>(shapeKind: T): DiscriminateUnion<Shape, 'kind', T> {
    switch (shapeKind) {
        case 'circle':
            return new Circle() as any // or `as DiscriminateUnion<Shape, 'kind', T>`
        case 'square':
            return new Square() as any
        default:
        throw Error('not valid shape')
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w18ZkW)

The common goto for such cases is [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads):

```ts
function makeShape<T extends ShapeKind>(shapeKind: T): DiscriminateUnion<Shape, 'kind', T> 
function makeShape(shapeKind: ShapeKind) : Shape {
    switch (shapeKind) {
        case 'circle':
            return new Circle()

        case 'square':
            return new Square()

        default:
        throw Error('not valid shape')

    }
}
/*
const newSquare: Square
*/
const newSquare = makeShape('square')
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3A73w)

While there are no errors here the implementation function actually doesn't check whether the returned type is compatible with function overloads and you can return it completely wrong:

```ts
function makeShape<T extends ShapeKind>(shapeKind: T): DiscriminateUnion<Shape, 'kind', T> 
function makeShape(shapeKind: ShapeKind) : Shape {
    switch (shapeKind) {
        case 'circle':
            return new Square() // wrong returned type but no error

        case 'square':
            return new Circle() // wrong returned type but no error

        default:
        throw Error('not valid shape')

    }
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wXRDOm)

Trying to impose strict type safety you may go further and try to check the returned type compatibility inside each of the `case` arms. Credits for the [brilliant idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67712372/3388225) for in-function type checking goes to [`jcalz`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2887218/jcalz):

```ts
function makeShape<T extends ShapeKind>(shapeKind: T): DiscriminateUnion<Shape, 'kind', T> 
function makeShape(shapeKind: ShapeKind) : Shape {
    switch (shapeKind) {
        case 'circle':
            const ret1 = new Square()
            const tmp1: typeof ret1 = (false as true) && makeShape(shapeKind) // errors now
            return ret1

        case 'square':
            const ret2 = new Circle()
            const tmp2: typeof ret2 = (false as true) && makeShape(shapeKind) // errors now
            return ret2

        default:
        throw Error('not valid shape')

    }
}
```

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mL9gvW)

It still has some artefacts in runtime and while that *type checking* `makeShape` call will not happen actually due to short circuting nature of `&&`. This looks kind of ugly and a requires a lot of ceremony to my taste.

I belive for non-critical paths annotating retuned values as `as any` is completely acceptible way.

Comment: Many thanks for the incredibly detailed and specific answer - have been going round and round on github and here trying to find my situation but without any joy, so really appreciate you pointing me in the right direction.