# Generic narrowing of dependent arguments and return values

Tags: typescript

I want to make TypeScript understand that multiple parameters as well as the return value of a function are dependent in their type such that narrowing one of them narrows all of them.

Consider this example:

```
type NumberType = {
    readonly type: "number"
    readonly value: number
}

type StringType = {
    readonly type: "string"
    readonly value: string
}

function test<T extends NumberType | StringType>(a: T, b: T): T {
    switch (a.type) {
        case "number": {
            console.log("Number case: ", a, b)
            const result: NumberType = {
                type: "number",
                value: a.value + b.value
            }
            return result
        }
        case "string": {
            console.log("String case: ", a, b)
            const result: StringType = {
                type: "string",
                value: a.value + b.value
            }
            return result
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4BVzQLxQN4BQUxUqEAhgCYD2AdgDYhSiQBcUARLYiqh0STJU6jKADdy9OBHbdkaAgF8CBFtADKwVAEtaAc0yQouQiVIUaDJmvYcAzlt17+ZoZdESpMqA536lKgBmcLQAxsDadMwQDgA86FAQAB7AELSUdrA8aIbQAD5Qmn4GWAB8ABTk7OgANFBI1QCU1fgCxHYA7trAoQAWUJUAdGqNrWZmoeR20FzZfOym40uhdHbU9BCD9NR65Rzw8qhQk9O2deR1SI1tSyQrtA7mdnD0wOwHvLnGY7e-NpxyXgcGo3X5mTzSdjkQYQ6AAanqMMk0lBt2UYMEEGAcFQtCeL2AqOI6NuJxmvicHAWRPG9zWGy2Oz2RScxym3mBUAu9WuGOIdOA+Ne7BZ+i+Jhpfywtgp+mBktusKhSK8UARSBVKL5UBJGLI2NxQsJv11OqUQA)

The parameters as well as the return value of `test` are all of the same type T. Now I would have assumed that narrowing one variable of this type (as done for a in the switch block) would narrow all of them. Though this is not the case. Within the switch block `b` is still `NumberType | StringType` and the result is still "<...> not assignable to T".

How could this be achieved?

Comment: With time, it came to me that changing return type of a function depending on the inputs of it is in most cases a bad design (i.e., `work({ async: true }): Promise<void>` vs `work({ async: false }): void`). Now I try to define separate functions for each return type (i.e., `work(): Promise<void>` vs `workSync(): void`).

Comment: You can still achieve that with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) or [overloading](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/function-overloading)

Comment: how do you do this with conditional types ? i could not get this to work... :/

Comment: I was talking about the return type specifically. Sorry for the confusion! For the narrowing-down thing, I don't think that there is a mechanism in TypeScript currently to "entangle" two values together in this way. I'd just use `as` (I know that's not ideal): `switch (a.type) { case "number": return a.value + (b.value as number) }`

Comment: You need a way to combine the arguments together in an array, and say somehow that "if one item is `NumberType`, then _all of them_ ` are `NumberType`". Essentially, the difference between `(NumberType | StringType)[]` and `NumberType[] | StringType[]`. That looks related to [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) but I'm not clever enough to figure out how exactly related.

Comment: ① Why are you adding `a` and `b` in your example?  Should it be `a.value + b.value` instead? Could you [edit] to be a [mre] without typos? ② Currently the only way for TS to follow your logic is to refactor to the form described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wQbO7N). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz: ah very cool. yeah, this seems to work (even though I need some more time to understand what exactly is going on there). thank you very much !

Comment: @jcalz: actually there seems to be still an issue with this code as it is possible to mix the types without complaining (and misinterpreting the type even). See here at bottom: https://shorturl.at/jvR28

Comment: Yes, TS is unsound with generics this way, I'd fix it to [this](https://tsplay.dev/N5VgZm) if you care much about that.

Comment: Ah okay... not exactly beautiful but does the trick. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript currently can't use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to affect the apparent constraints of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters.  When you check `a.type`, the compiler can narrow the type of `a`, but it doesn't do anything at all to `T`.  So therefore the apparent type of `b` is unaffected, as well as the return type, and your code results in corresponding errors.

There are various open issues in GitHub asking to support  for this or something like it, like [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) and [microsoft/TypeScript#27808](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27808), but for now it's not part of the language.

---

Currently the only way to get the compiler to follow logic like this is to abandon control-flow based operations (`if`/`else`, `switch`/`case`, etc) and rewrite in terms of a single block of generic code.  So you could put your different cases as methods of a `typeFuncs` object whose keys are the possible values of `a.type`.  Without worrying too much about the types right now, the refactored implementation looks like:

```
const typeFuncs = {
    number: (a, b) => {
        console.log("Number case: ", a, b)
        const result: NumberType = {
            type: "number",
            value: a.value + b.value
        }
        return result
    },
    string: (a, b) => {
        console.log("String case: ", a, b)
        const result: StringType = {
            type: "string",
            value: a.value + b.value
        }
        return result
    }
}

function func1(a, b) {
    return typeFuncs[a.type](a, b);
}
```

So the case analysis has been replaced by an indexing operation.

---

Once we change that, we still need to refactor your types so the compiler can see the behavior of `typeFuncs[a.type](a, b)` as acting generically.  Right now this can only be accomplished by writing all types in terms of a "base" key-value type, and generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that type, or into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over that type.  The technique is described in detail in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).

For this example, I'd do it this way. The base type is `TypeMap`, which is a simple mapping from the `type` property to the corresponding `value` property:

```
interface TypeMap {
    number: number;
    string: string;
}
```

Then your `NumberType` and `StringType` can be written as specializations of a generic utility type `Type<K>`:

```
type Type<K extends keyof TypeMap> =
    { [P in K]: { readonly type: P, readonly value: TypeMap[P] } }[K]

type NumberType = Type<"number">;
type StringType = Type<"string">;
```

Here, `Type<K>` is a *distributive object type* (as coined in ms/TS#47109), of the form `{[P in K]: F<P>}[K]`.  That distributes the type over [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) in `K`, so that `Type<"number" | "string">` is equivalent to `Type<"number"> | Type<"string">` (and thus `NumberType | StringType`).

These types are equivalent to yours, but now the compiler can see them as part of a single generic type operation.

Now we can give `typeFuncs` the following type:

```
type TypeFuncs = 
  { [P in keyof TypeMap]: (a: Type<P>, b: Type<P>) => Type<P> };

const typeFuncs: TypeFuncs = {
    number: (a, b) => {
        console.log("Number case: ", a, b)
        const result: NumberType = {
            type: "number",
            value: a.value + b.value
        }
        return result
    },
    string: (a, b) => {
        console.log("String case: ", a, b)
        const result: StringType = {
            type: "string",
            value: a.value + b.value
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

It's a mapped type over `TypeMap` which, again, can be seen by the compiler as a single generic type operation.  Each member of `TypeFuncs` is of the generic function type `(a: Type<P>, b: Type<P>) => Type<P>` for some `P`.  And now `func1()` can be given this typing:

```
function func1<K extends keyof TypeMap, L extends K>(a: Type<K>, b: Type<L>): Type<K> {
    return typeFuncs[a.type](a, b);
}
```

Here we're generic in `K` corresponding to `a.type` and `b.type`.  Both parameters and the return type are now `Type<K>`.  Note that I've added a second `L` type parameter for `b`.  It's constrained to `K` so it will effectively be the same as `K`.  But if you call `func1()` with two different types (e.g., `StringType` for `a` and `NumberType` for `b`) the compiler will infer `K` from `a` alone (e.g., `"string"`) and not from both `a` and `b` (e.g., `"string" | "number"`).  This allows us to block inference on `b` as per [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  It's an annoying unsoundness we have to work around, as per [microsoft/TypeScript#48730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48730)

Anyway, the compiler sees `typeFuncs[a.type]` as `(a: Type<K>, b: Type<K>) => Type<K>`.  Since `a` and `b` are both of type `Type<K>`, then it lets you call `typeFuncs[a.type](a, b)`, and the return type is `Type<K>`, which type checks.

---

So there you go. This answers the question "how can this be achieved", but it might not necessarily be worth your effort.  Often in cases like this the most expedient thing is to just use [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to loosen the type checking enough to allow your code to proceed. That gives up some compiler-verified safety, but doesn't require a major refactoring.  Which basic approach is taken depends on how you assign the relative importance of safety vs ease.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOECydPIDeAUMmciAK4C2ARtAFwU31QDcp5AzmFKAOZMefEPw4BfYsTBYUGbAB4A0sggAPSCAAmXZAGsI6APYw0svJgB8yALxFkAbQAKyUMiUBdJoWRQIcLSMQABt0ZBlsJicAGl9-QJCwgDc4YMoIJnlcfGcPZHF8h08pAHoS11NjSgoICC1wgAsIamlZZAA5Fmgs2zNFACIqOmh+yw4IlABlXgEeuyyFfuEBUY5W7D6IADFKEARdOx9nVxB9QxNNiy9kAAo4TNkFJ0tY2gfFZ4BKW2sF5-yOAggjxwrIdnsuO9trt9r0SORmMMoEw7q9vjZrPCEeQgSAuEZghAAHTBIz8G79TpI5AIOBcDLIfqxOBozjYmnAsBxLiUYJgJhU1hzIhs9nkCZMQZdKBM0Vi5ApNIMuBExXpZAAamQtFVqXScvIknlfjAlCgpz8PL5ovE0VFy1EKJZ2vRmINZFx+MJJLJFOmIn4NLpDKZyGdtE+7o5eK5lt5-OQ-tmbUOUYREsZDv4svlCLVyt1Ss12sL+vlRrFJrNFogVrANuIkmIMBhYGAQWQLb2AEZlKoNBBtLoDMZTFkLLEADL9zQ6dyWO5Q5QvbVLyeWT5LpRuhFV82g7Dg-YOFUTDyol0SKSerkgbsC6XCrFkDNSpE58j5pgAZkbxBvFAAEwPkiT6iq+QysB+ZBfsgACsf4AVw96JjMohgemsiSlm0EKnqIYABIQMEpL9IhnLIFwwGoQGGHilhmZodmdp5vhkoAOpGFAwRaGRkgAea3a9F2CDdjcd6xCAgGRgJyHCTCYnIbEVEyRR5pyXYIliRJlHSUAA)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to remove the [generic constraints](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#handbook-content) you can achieve the narrowing with [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) otherwise things like these are quite uncomfortable to implement (See [Type constraints for overloaded function in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67704615/type-constraints-for-overloaded-function-in-typescript)).

However, regardless of the narrowing, when adding/concatenating `a.value + b.value` (I assume you meant to do that) you'll always need [Type Assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions).

```
type NumberType = {
  readonly type: "number";
  readonly value: number;
};

type StringType = {
  readonly type: "string";
  readonly value: string;
};

function test(a: NumberType, b: NumberType): NumberType;
function test(a: StringType, b: StringType): StringType;
function test(
  a: NumberType | StringType,
  b: NumberType | StringType
): NumberType | StringType {
  switch (a.type) {
    case "number": {
      console.log("Number case: ", a, b);
      const result: NumberType = {
        type: "number",
        value: a.value + (b as NumberType).value
      };
      return result;
    }
    case "string": {
      console.log("String case: ", a, b);
      const result: StringType = {
        type: "string",
        value: a.value + (b as StringType).value
      };
      return result;
    }
  }
}

const result1 = test(
  {type: "number", value: 1},
  {type: "number", value: 2}
);
// const result1: NumberType
const result2 = test(
  {type: "string", value: ""},
  {type: "string", value: ""}
);
// const result2: StringType
```

---

A possible flaw (depending on your real use case) is the [Excess Property Checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#excess-property-checks) which you don't have when using the generics.

```
const result3 = test(
  { type: "string", value: "", anotherProperty: "" },
//                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  {type: "string", value: ""}
);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwEYQE4BVzQLxQN4BQUUqEAhgCYD2AdgDYhSiQBcUARDYiquwNxES5avUYA3MnTgQ2XZGgEBfAQWbQAysFQBLGgHNMkKLkLFSlWgyZY27AM5bde-oPMirEqTKgOd%20pSoAZnA0AMbA2rRMEA4AFGRs8PIYWAA0UEiJ3GiGEACUWcm5AsFhEVHAMcDxbJp%20BmkZtY76uQVQdU7FBKXhkTTRcYIJsNkpRgA%20HS0NkKmCmaNFWFBTna1YBO1JPLmr0-V7pj4A7trAoQAWUPEAdGp5%20ILEoWR20Jxj7GzHxC%200diodAgtzoVD0sXYOzQUFe71s6TI6SQeQEfz%20oQBwCEdjgdGAhV2KxMz3R1lYHDkPHY8zJf080jYZFuDOgAGobkgoG8lkTIHkWZJpKTiMoRUJgHBUANSLj8Wi-opSXCPr4nN8nnTMTRAcDQeDIes9LC3t4adzkajxdqHDi8QSDl1iZq6eSzWr9DTxcRWUzBV4oBzYlyeUa2v7hXSxXTSJLpXb5aSlaKCEqCDbsbL7QBGYyDaqCPBqWxUtDm31QbOKWn4YuUr7pCsAJiVVoA9G3YViE8Bs4ScpsMz2m3nKkNiEWbBwPc5G0Kzexq4W6-YZuX57ZF1sBB2uzrMzF7U3modNunu1n8QBmUdVWKFt22GfrrybxE0KjAS5oAAKqCokCoKAm5QEuE4rs%20c6vhwW6okAA)